# setting up mod-rewrite to handle queries with and without data

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have the following modrewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /blog.php?date=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Which is pretty straightforward. My question is, how do I get this rewrite to direct to `blog.php` if no variables are listed?

blog.php is written to both produce the article listing if no variables are present, and also to create the individual listing if one is present.

**Edit:**
blog.php works fine without mod rewrite. If I go to `http://host/blog.php` it lists all my articles. If I go to `http://host/blog/2010-10-05/blog-title/` it shows my single entry. Similarly, if I go to `http://host/blog.php?date=2010-10-05&title=blog-title` I get a single entry. However, I want `http://host/blog/` to list all my entries as well.

I guess the question is: Does this require a second rewrite rule? And if so, how do I get the two to play nice.

Comment: `Which is pretty straightforward. My question is, how do I get this rewrite to direct to blog.php if no variables are listed?` care to make an example ? not entirelly sure i understood your point... **From what i understood it seems more like a programming issue then a rewrite rule issue.** It would be a blog.php programming thing to instead of trying to show the article to show something else when there is no available article on the given variables.

Comment: Or are you saying you just want to redirect blog when people type blog like: `RewriteRule ^(blog|blog/)$ /blog.php [L]` which would come before your other rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments talk, there you go ;)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(blog|blog/)$ /blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /blog.php?date=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

The blog alone comes first so if the user have typed blog or blog/ it will go to blog.php and stop there, if that requirement does not meet it will move to the second rule.

`(blog|blog/)$`

> The $ is used to prevent that blog
>   matchs blog.html or anything else.
>
> The | is use as an operator OR so if
>   it is blog OR blog/
>
> [L] means LAST so if the rule is meet
>   no other rule will be take into
>   consideration after it.